# Problems with touchpad in Cinnamon

Tags: touchpad, cinnamon

I've installed Cinnamon in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Two fingers scrolling and tap click don't work, despite in the mouse/touchpad setting panel both options are enabled. I typed

```
$ synclient TapButton1=1
synclient  VertTwoFingerScroll=1
```

and all works fine. My problem is how to make these commands persistent after a system restart.

Answer (score 5):

Cinnamon on Ubuntu has two different 'System Settings'. Search for System Settings in the menu and you'll notice that this is, the case. Obviously then you can just change your touchpad settings in the other System Settings window and you're all sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings, Devices then "Mouse & Touchpad"
In Touchpad section you can enable Two finger scrolling or Edge scrolling.